# makefile with directory tree creation suitable for parallel (-j ) build

Tags: build-process, build, makefile

My project needs temporary directories which are created during the build using mkdir -p similarly to this:

```
all: dirtree $(OBJFILES)

dirtree: 
  @mkdir -p $(BUILD)/temp_directory
```

But this approach cannot be used with the -j switch, because first of the OBJFILES get compiled before the mkdir target is made.

Is there a standard way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem with your makefile is that creation of your object files does not depend on creation of the relevant directories (only a phony "all" target does).  This kind of dependency is necessary for `-j` option, and even without it your makefile works only by chance.  There are two (right) ways to impose the dependency in question.

**Directories as separate targets**

You created the target for directory creation; what left is just put it as a prerequisite to object file rule:

```
$(BUILD)/temp_directory/%.o: %.c   |   dirtree
        $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

The pipe symbol `|` means that dirtree is an ["order only prerequisite"](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types).  It is used when "dirtree" is a prerequisite but changes in the dirtree do not invalidate object files and do not affect the outcome of compilation command.

Use of "order-only" prerequisite is important here. The thing is that `dirtree` target would be remade at each Make invocation.  That would cause everything that depends on it be remade as well, so it would rebuild *all* object files every time.

**Create directories in shell commands**

Another way is to ensure that the directory is created immediately before you invoke compilation

```
$(BUILD)/temp_directory/%.o: %.c
        @mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

Note the usage of `$(@D)`.  This is expanded as "the directory for the target file".  So it may be used uniformly in many places, and even with aid of a variable.

```
Mkdir=@mkdir -p $(@D)
$(BUILD)/temp_directory/%.o: %.c
        $(Mkdir)
        $(CC) $^ -o $@
$(INSTALL_DIR)/%: src_dir/%
        $(Mkdir)
        cp -p $^ $@
```

---

Both ways ensure that the directory is created before the compilation commands are invoked.  Both ways require you to write some text (either `| dirtree` or `$(Mkdir)`) at each rule that needs it.  Both ways are `-j` compatible, but the second solution requires `mkdir -p` to be thread-safe (as two such commands at once may try to create the same directory, and one of them would fail).

While most systems implement it in such a way that `mkdir -p` is more or less thread safe, on some systems ([as in some Solaris systems, for example](http://www.mail-archive.com/automake@gnu.org/msg08273.html)), they are less thread-safe than the others.  However, even in GNU toolchain `mkdir -p` may fail if they simultaneously invoke the same `mkdir(2)` library call.

If you want to be *very* safe, you can work this around as well.  What could be the problem?  That two `mkdir -p` scripts try to create the same directory, and clash somewhere inside C library.  Then, one of these `mkdir`-s will succeed, and the other will fail.  However, if the `mkdir` you invoked failed, then it could be thread-unsafety-related failure only if the directory had been created by a concurrent `mkdir`.  So it would be enough to just check that the target directory is created after `mkdir` invocation:

```
Mkdir=@mkdir -p $(@D) || test -d $(@D)
```

(This solution also has an issue with mode: mkdir may fail when directory exists, but doesn't conform to umask, so you might want to check that as well.  But that's too much I guess.)

Comment: `mkdir -p` is not `-j` compatible. Two processes doing `mkdir -p /a/b/c` race and one fails with EEXIST. There are no mythical _internal filesystem locks_.

Comment: @Maxim, thank you for your comment.  Here's another, even more thread-safe version.  Can you find any flaws in it as well?

Comment: I can see the update. Well, because of the race condition I mentioned, (`make -p` basically does `if(!exists(dir)) mkdir(dir);` for each directory in the path) when one process creates /a/b/c and another creates /a/b/cc, a concurrent `mkdir -p` may fail creating directory /a/b if another process has already created it just before this process does `mkdir(dir)` call. The bullet proof solution is to make generated files depend on their directory (using order only GNU make prerequisite) and use a script that emulates `mkdir -p` but does not fail with EEXIST on `mkdir(dir)`.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: If the `mkdir` program gets `EEXIST` after calling `mkdir(dir)`, and the `-p` option has been specified, then the `mkdir` program should exit successfully as long as `dir` is a directory and has the correct permissions. In the case of a race between two processes, `dir` *will* be a directory and *will* have the correct permissions, so `mkdir -p` should exit successfully. It is a bug in the `mkdir` program if it does not. For instance, in `mkdir` from GNU coreutils there is a function named `mkancesdirs` that is specifically designed to handle parallel processes.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. However, I can say this: if your build breaks when you add parallelism, then it's an indication that you haven't defined the dependencies correctly. Ask yourself, "Do the directories need to exist before the object files are generated?" If the answer is "yes", then the directories should be listed as *prerequisites* of the object files. In other words:

```
${OBJFILES}: dirtree
```

And yes, that is pretty much the standard way to do this :)

Comment: This does not work for me. An objfile has two prerequisities - dirtree and .c file. Make can start with making .c file first (order is not defined). Therefore I had to add dirtree dependency to the rule making .obj from .c. Fresh build works well but when I change just one .c file all .c files are rebuild.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that make is *generating* the .c files and that after they are made, the .o files are compiled?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, may English is far from perfect. I wanted to say that make will *process* .c (input .c output .o).

Answer (score 2):

You could have the rules for building the object files call `mkdir -p` as their first action.