# Can a makefile have a directory as a target?

Tags: makefile, makepp

I am trying to say "the download of the git repository will only work if the directory yank/ exists. If the directory yank/ does not exist then make it"

```
yank/gist.el/gist.el : yank
    cd yank ; git clone http://github.com/defunkt/gist.el.git 

yank:
    mkdir yank
```

I am using makepp - http://makepp.sf.net
and am getting the error:

```
[metaperl@andLinux ~/edan/pkg/gist.el] makepp
makepp: Loading makefile `/home/metaperl/edan/pkg/gist.el/Makeppfile'
makepp: Entering directory `/home/metaperl/edan/pkg/gist.el'
mkdir yank
mkdir: cannot create directory `yank': File exists
makepp: error: Failed to build target `/home/metaperl/edan/pkg/gist.el/yank' [1]
makepp: 0 files updated, 0 phony targets built and 1 target failed
[metaperl@andLinux ~/edan/pkg/gist.el]
```

But why would it try to make the yank directory if it exists? The "source" has already ben created...

Comment: We already had a discussion on creating directories: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950926/create-directories-using-make-file.  You might also want to know that [the way you create directories is not thread-safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894427/makefile-with-directory-tree-creation-suitable-for-parallel-j-build).

Comment: @Pavel: the way the directory is created is fine, because it's a dependency of the file. In the example you cite, the problem is precisely that the directory is not a dependency of the targets that use it but of another target, which doesn't do any good.

Comment: @Gilles, ok, you're right, I mingled the issues.  Just wanted to persuade you that directories as targets is not a good option...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, a `Makefile` can have a directory as target.

Your problem could be that the `cd` doesn't do what you want: it does `cd` and the `git clone` is carried out in the original directory (the one you `cd`ed from, *not* the one you `cd`ed to). This is because for every command in the `Makefile` an extra shell is created. A workaround is to run `cd` and clone as one command with the shell's `&&`.

This should work:

```
bla/f: dir
    cd dir && touch f

dir:
    mkdir dir
```

Comment: True, and on general principles makefiles should always `&&` rather than `;`. However this can't be an issue here: `cd` only runs *after* the `yank` target has been remade.

Comment: I usually use a target of `dir/.dirstamp` instead of `dir` with a rule of `mkdir -p dir && touch $@`.  The timestamps on dirs in unix change when the contents of the directory change preventing dependent rules from running.

Answer (score 19):

[In a makefile, is a directory name a phony target or "real" target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248300/in-a-makefile-is-a-directory-name-a-phony-target-or-real-target)

> What you need is an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html).

```
yank/gist.el/gist.el : | yank
    cd yank ; git clone http://github.com/defunkt/gist.el.git

yank:
    mkdir -p yank
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a Makefile can have a directory as target.

However, you shouldn't.  When a file is added or removed from a directory, its mtime is updated.  This can cause weird behaviour by causing multiple targets depending on a single directory to become implicitly rebuilt by one another.  So as a rule of thumb, you should avoid using directories as targets and/or dependencies..

```
all: d/a d/b

d/a d/b: d
  rm -f $@
  touch $@

d:
  mkdir $@
```

The output from running this multiple times looks like...

```
$ make
mkdir d
rm -f d/a
touch d/a
rm -f d/b
touch d/b

$ make
rm -f d/a
touch d/a

$ make
rm -f d/b
touch d/b

$ make
rm -f d/a
touch d/a
```

Answer (score 1):

Your makefile should do what you expect. Since yank has no dependency, it won't be remade if it exists. So this looks like a bug in makepp. You could confirm this by trying your makefile with a traditional implementation of make.