# Prepending a path on make

Tags: g++, makefile

In my makefile I have an object variable. I need to prepend obj/ to every .o file. How would I do this?

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-C -Wall
LDFLAGS=-lsqlite3 -lpthread -ldl
SOURCES=main.cpp Database.cpp actionInit.cpp TileSet.cpp Player.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

EXECUTABLE=mahjong-counter

all: bin $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)

bin:
    mkdir -p bin

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $< -c -o $@

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXECUTABLE)

clean:
    rm $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: Your makefile has a couple of issues.  Aside from using `$(CC)` instead of `$(CXX)`, you might want to [avoid creating directories in a separate target, as it's parallel-build-unsafe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894427/makefile-with-directory-tree-creation-suitable-for-parallel-j-build).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want CXX, not CC. CC is for C compiler, not the C++ compiler
In any case, I believe the following should work:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-C -Wall
LDFLAGS=-lsqlite3 -lpthread -ldl

OBJ_DIR = obj
BIN_DIR = bin
EXECUTABLE=mahjong-counter

SOURCES= main.cpp Database.cpp actionInit.cpp TileSet.cpp Player.cpp
OBJECTS= $(SOURCES:%.cpp=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)

all: dirs $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXECUTABLE)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

dirs:
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)

.PHONY: dirs all
```

Comment: make: *** No rule to make target `mainobj/%.o', needed by `all'. Stop. It seems to take the /%.o literally.

Comment: Did you add the slash after $(OBJ_DIR)? It looks hidden

Comment: `CC` is for the C compiler, whether or not it's `gcc` is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, yeah that's what I meant. Edited. +1@Jack

Answer (score 12):

You could use more expressive version of substitution you employed when assigning `OBJECTS`

```
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:%.cpp=obj/%.o)
```

or use a standard text transformation function

```
OBJECTS=$(addprefix obj/,$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))
```

Comment: `$(addprefix)` is a GNU extension.

Comment: Does anybody still use a non-GNU make?

Comment: @Maxim: People on non-GNU systems (BSD, Solaris, IRIX, AIX, ...)?